# Using XPages with Freemarker help needed

Tags: xpages, velocity, freemarker

I would like to use Freemarker template engine in my XPages app but cant get it to work in XPages environment. The problem I have is related to template path which I don't know how to setup correctly. Freemarker simply assumes that templates resides somewhere on file system. I put my template file into the same directory as related java class exists. The path to such file is something like this `xspnsf://server:0/xpages_tests.nsf/WEB-INF/classes/tcl/` which doesn't work for me. Is there anyone having experience with this? I simply need directory path to nsf that is accepted by File() constructor. This virtual `xspnsf://....` is not understandable for java File object.

Here is the template path code for Freemarker:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("??????"));
Template temp = cfg.getTemplate("tmp.ftl");
```

Comment: Freemarker seems to use the normal File classes in Java. They can't load files from URIs. Unless you can provide your templates as streams (you would need a resolver class for includes), Freemaker isn't suitable

Comment: Do you have experience with some other templating system working with XPages?

Comment: @stwissel: Would you please look at the Manual or the API docs next time before answering... FreeMarker can load templates out-of-the-box from URI-s (see `URLTemplateLoader`), from "classpath" (`ClassTemplateLoader`), from Webapp context (`WebappTemplateLoader`). Plus you can easily load from any other resources by implementing the `TemplateLoader` interface. You just create the `TemplateLoader` you need and pass it to`Configuration.setTemplateLoader`. FreeMarker doesn't assume that templates are plain files at all.

Comment: @ddekany That is what I said: Unless you can provide them as stream -> seems you can. But that wasn't the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Velocity (http://velocity.apache.org/) instead. It allows You to create custom resources loaders which can easily load templates from any place (for example from documents from notes db).

I have seen it used many times in different xpage projects and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!! I have a velocity experience from Apache Click, never realised that custom resource loader is possible...

Comment: It's also possible in FreeMarker BTW. See `TemplateLoader` and `Configuration.setTemplateLoader`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing the templates together with the classes (if I understand well), can't you use `cfg.setClassForTemplateLoading(SomeClassFromThere.class, "/com/example/yourapplication/templates")`?